# W3C Validator thinks site is using XHTML; it's not

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype, w3c, w3c-validation

The [Renfrewshire Council website](http://www.renfrewshire.gov.uk) uses the HTML4.01 DOCTYPE, as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

When this site is run through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it states that the site is using XHTML1.0.

Can anyone tell me why this discrepancy exists?

Comment: If you look at the source code of the online website, the doctype is XHTML 1.0

Comment: Thanks Aequanox - I think there may be a discrepancy between what exists outwith and within the organisational firewall.

Answer (score 2):

The page has this doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

So, the validator is right to think that it uses XHTML.

Comment: Hmm... curious. I'm looking at it from within the organisational firewall, where it's definitely using the HTML4.01 DOCTYPE. Thanks for the prompt reply!